# Need barcode & keyboard to work separately

Tags: linux, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to read from a USB barcode reader in one interface & at the same time use the keyboard & mouse to write data in a diffrent interface application?
My application is running as web application.
Also can it work under unix?

Comment: Are you saying the barcode scanner is on your web server or the client PC? Do you have control over the browser, such that you can write a plug-in?

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux it's easy; configure Xorg such that the reader is not a core input device, then use the event subsystem to read the input events directly from the reader.